# mail() function in PHP return bool false

Tags: php, email, xampp

I'm trying to send email using `mail()` function in php.

I'm on Localhost.

Here is my code :

```
$result = mail('recipient@gmail.com', 'Hello world', 'Some Message');
var_dump($result);
```

It gives me this :

`bool(false)`

I'm facing this from last 2 days, please help !

My configuration of xampp is according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost).

Comment: I would recommend that you use a tried and tested mail lib instead, like PHPMailer, SwiftMailer or similar instead of the low level `mail()`-function. That will not only give you a way more verbose API, but it's also easier to debug and makes your code more portable since you then easily can use some SMTP-server, which is recommended and won't depend on any server configurations.

Comment: Can i use it with core Php, I've read some post regarding SwiftMailer, there are stuff related to OOP ? @ Magnus Eriksson

Comment: Both those libraries are just PHP without depending on anything else (other than a valid mail address). Just donwload it (or use composer) and follow their documentation. Yes, they are built with OOP, just like most libraries/code nowadays.

Comment: Okay ! let me try the PHPMailer , could you please share some useful stuff ? "@magnus Eriksson

Comment: I can recommend reading the documentation. They have all kinds of examples there.

Comment: I used the PHPMailer, and it worked , really happy to sort out this , thank you so much  ! @Magnus Eriksson

Answer (score 0):

The reason is always the **sendmail_from** and **sendmail_path** are not correct with respect to your system in the **php.ini** settings even if the mail goes successfully but it will return false if the path is not correct. Please check those.

Comment: _"The reason is always the sendmail_from"_ - That's a big claim! You mean that there is _no other_ possible explanation for why the `mail()`-function can return false?

Comment: Here is my configuration :
sendmail_from = mehmoodsft@gmail.com.
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

Comment: I have faced this problem several times only because of wrong configurations. i.e why I claim that. But in this case seems like configurtion is ok. 

Is that problem solved ?